# Casting pointers to const in container types

Tags: c++, pointers, casting, containers, constants

C++ provides implicit conversion from `T *` to `const T *`.

If I use `T *` within a container class now, like in `vector<T *>`, then there is of course no implicit conversion to `vector<const T *>` anymore.

Using an `reinterpret_cast` seems to work to cast the entire container, but is it actually safe to do this?

```
template <typename T>
const vector<const T *> & constVector(const vector<T *> & vec) {
    return reinterpret_cast<const vector<const T *> &>(vec);
}

// Usage:
vector<int *> vec1;
vector<const int *> vec2 = constVector(vec1);
```

Comment: _"implicit type casting"_: it's called a _conversion_ ;)

Comment: Why do want to do this?

Comment: @PeterRuderman In order to be able to pass a `vector<T *>` to a function which takes a `vector<const T *>`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> but is it actually safe to do this?

No, this is **undefined behavior**. It is only safe to use `reinterpret_cast` in a very limited set of scenarios, please refer to [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reinterpret_cast).

---

If ownership is not a concern, you might want to use (or implement) a `const` **view** over a non-`const` range of objects. Googling for `span` would be a good start. `std::string_view` is an example of this for `std::string`.

Comment: If `span` is not an option, you can make a `basic_string_view` to anything. Toy example: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/bc5dc005ecd07e27. And as a perk, you've got a bunch of useful [methods on your view](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string_view). (You might want to specialize `std::char_traits` for your type though.)

Comment: Even though this is undefined behavior according to the C++ standard, can it actually fail in practice if the memory alignment of `vector<T *>` and `vector<const T *>` are identical (which I assume they are)?

Comment: It's dangerous to rely on something working practice since future changes to the compiler or standard library could change the behaviour of your code.

Comment: Keep in mind that because vector is a class template, vector<T*> and vector<T const*> could (in theory) have completely different representations.